# Add columns to Excel Pivot

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

Suppose I have a list of citizen grouped in a pivot:

```
Citizen | Count
Chinese   153
Italian   245
French    236
```

I would like to add a new column to show the country **in this way**:

```
Citizen | Country | Count
Chinese   China     153
Italian   Italy     245
French    France    236
```

The problem is that when i add Country as a new column it does something like this:

```
Citizen | French | Italy  | China | Count
Chinese                      153     153
Italian             245              245
French     236                       236
```

So how do i collpase another column inside a "single" column like the previous example?

An option is to add "country" as a new rows and the results is:

```
Citizen | Count
Chinese   153
|-China   153
Italian   245
|-Italy   245
French    236
|-France  236
```

but i'd like to avoid this option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this one do the following:

```
Citizen | Count
Chinese   153
|-China   153
Italian   245
|-Italy   245
French    236
|-France  236
```

1. Select the pivot
2. Design -> Report Layout -> Show in Tabular Form